# My first Python Scrapy cannot work

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to Python and Scrapy. and now i am working on crawling and needs to use both of them. below is my code and no output can be retrieved. May i know how can i solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

```
 import scrapy
 from loginform import fill_login_form


 class FirstSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'test'

    login_url = 'URL'
    login_user = 'account'
    login_password = 'password'

    def start_requests(self):
        print('Step 1')
        return scrapy.Request(self.login_url, callback=self.parse_login)

    def parse_login(self, response):
        print('Step 2')
        data, url, method = fill_login_form(response.url, response.body,
                                            self.login_user, self.login_password)

        return scrapy.FormRequest(url, formdata=dict(data),
                           method=method, callback=self.start_crawl)

    def start_crawl(self, response):
        list = response.xpath("//a[@class='menu_section active']/text()").extract()
        print(list)
        if 'back overview' in list:
            print('Good to go')
        else:
            print("Failed")
```

> output : Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: how do you run the spider ?

Comment: Are you using a real URL instead of `login_url = 'URL'`?

Comment: Hi Nordle, yes, i replaced the real url and login being posting there.

Comment: What part is not working? Exit code 0 means exit without errors. What does the output log says?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using scrapy shell to debug your program.
try accessing the response from the shell and see if you able to fetch the elements.